# Failed to instantiate one or more class TextInputEditText internal error

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, material-design

I am working on an android project and everything was working fine, until I started getting following error.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find dimen
>   resource matching value 0x10500E0 (resolved name:
>   default_magnifier_width) in current configuration.    at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1151)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1127)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1131)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources_Delegate.java:657)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:742)
>     at
>   android.widget.Magnifier$Builder.applyDefaults(Magnifier.java:1162)
>     at android.widget.Magnifier$Builder.(Magnifier.java:1157)     at
>   android.widget.Magnifier.createBuilderWithOldMagnifierDefaults(Magnifier.java:155)
>     at android.widget.Editor.(Editor.java:399)    at
>   android.widget.TextView.createEditorIfNeeded(TextView.java:12923)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.setRawInputType(TextView.java:6607)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.setInputType(TextView.java:6691)  at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1454)    at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:88)  at
>   android.widget.EditText.(EditText.java:84)  at
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.(AppCompatEditText.java:73)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.(TextInputEditText.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.(TextInputEditText.java:46)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:393)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:138)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:299)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:328)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:509)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$4(RenderTask.java:638)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

It's showing this error for TextInputEditText, stating

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

I tried following options :

1. Invalid cache and restart
2. clean and build project
3. migrating to "support" libraries
4. changing the parent theme to "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"

but nothing worked, as I think logs states that it's internal value error of dimen for the current configuration. 
nothing worked.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        tools:context=".activities.Register">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_generate_bg_ui"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline34"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline28"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/bank_details"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_balance_wallet_black_24dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline30"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
            android:contentDescription="@string/bank_balance_image" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline33">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/accountHolderName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/account_holder_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/bankAccountNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/account_number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmBankAccountNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/confirm_account_number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutIFSC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/ifscCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/ifsc"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBankDetails"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:onClick="onSubmit"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline29"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline28"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutIFSC" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

This is my gradle file :

```
dependencies {

    //  androidx dependency
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navigationFragment_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$google_auth_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:$google_play_core"
}
```

Comment: show your code it help us find the bug

Comment: @Amitpandey, I have added the code, I have removed the inputType parameter from all the TextInputEditText and it's rendering now, but the problem is I still need to add inputtype for customer's convenince.

Comment: As i check your xml i dont find any issue show your   programming code

Comment: Problem is in xml file only, Programming code doesn't have to do with the error. I have gradle dependencies.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' try with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue, though it still generated another problem.

To solve this internal problem, I just removed "android:inputType" tag from every TextInputEditText which lets android studio parse the ui, Now the another problem that arrives is that I cannot specify inputType which restricts me to use that functionality. I have tried alternative to use EditText instead of TextInputEditText, but that didn't work as it ended up the previous problem only.

Edit :

If you cannot specify inputType using xml tags, then you can use setInputTupe() java method to specify the inputType.

Comment: Though I haven't really tested your code, but seems like a bug to me. Can you create a minimal reproducible example, this way you can figure out more easily if there is a bug in your code or in google's implementation of TextInputEditText and then you can also file a bug report in google's issue tracker.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal, I did reported it. There might be a problem with the value or a parameter from "Internal" code, as you can see from the logs "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find dimen resource matching value 0x10500E0 (resolved name: default_magnifier_width) in current configuration." which is internal value error from the layout itself.

Comment: I did checked on various sources with same error, but could not find the way. It's quite unique problem.